Where to put the AES key?
I'm developing a Windows application with data that I want to encrypt. I have no idea about encryption, so I've started to read about encryption algorithms.
One of the algorithms I have read about was AES. If I have understood it well, AES use a key.
My question is: Would this key be included with the data I want to encrypt and decrypt?

Modern operating systems have dedicated key stores - e.g. Key Chain on macOS and iOS, Windows and Android should have equivalents.

@DannyNiu Thanks a lot. This leads me to another question: if the content to be decrypted and the key to decrypt it were on the same computer, wouldn't it be very easy to decrypt it?

@VansFannel The reason that you'd use a system's keystore is that the access to the key can be made harder than you can do with just your application. But yes, unless you have a locked down device it will always be possible in some way to use the key and decrypt. This is akin what plays for DRM systems. What you should want to achieve is a compartmented access control system. From a cryptographic standpoint: sometimes it helps to also use asymmetric algorithms as then the encryption key can be public & separate from the decryption key.

Anyway, you seem too un-experienced to handle encryption programming. Do read around before committing your code. Keywords for you to search: hardware security module, Crypto API (Win32), public-key encryption, key encapsulation mechanism, PKCS (public-key cryptography standard), authenticated encryption, blockcipher mode of operation.

@DannyNiu Don't you think that read a 450 pages book is too much to understand how a public key works? Thanks.

@VansFannel You don't need to read all those to use or to understand what a PKC algorithm does. You only read the gory details to understand inner workings of an algorithm.
